# Unableto test links by using link text in selenium web driver, If link contains <br>

Tags: java, selenium

Link : 
Call or Mail for


FREE TRIAL

My Code Here:

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Call or Mail for FREE TRIAL")).isDisplayed());
```

Comment: Link text is one of the weakest locators. You could try searching by partial link text, but really you're probably better off using XPath or CSS locators.

Answer (score 0):

If link contains break then use '\n' for verifying or using it.

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Call or Mail for\n\nFREE TRIAL")).isDisplayed());
```

please cross verify your number of breaks and use '\n' for every break.

Answer (score 0):

Add the html code so we can check the code you wrote and can suggest the other best way if possible

Answer (score 0):

There must be space before and after the link so better to use xpath for object identification

```
     Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Call or Mail for FREE TRIAL')]")).isDisplayed());
```